# Selecting specific landcover type, filtering date and clipping for MODIS land cover data

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I am trying to select type 5 land cover from the MODIS 500m dataset for the year 2001, and then extract out the projection for that layer. However, my script doesn't seem to work because I still obtain a 'collection' when I am expecting an image (since there is 1 dataset per year and I am selecting a specific layer). I know it doesn't work because when i try to extract the projection using projection(), it gives me the error, 'modis.projection is not a function'. I know it works if i put .first for the image collection, but I want to apply this to 2005 as well (and understand where I went wrong).

Another thing I noticed is that the .clip function and .filterBound doesn't seem to work with MODIS (even when I use the .first function.

Why is that so?

```
// Script that doesn't work and gives the error 
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
           .filterDate('2001-01-01','2001-12-31')
           .select('LC_Type5')
           .clip(geometry);

print('MODIS projection:', modis.projection());
```

```
// Script that works but doesn't end up clipping the image 
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1').select('LC_Type5')
            .first()
            .clip(cprBasin);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of points that I hope clarifies things:

- `filterBounds()` must be called on an `ee.ImageCollection` or `ee.FeatureCollection`. It filters out images or features from the collection.
- `clip()` must be called on an `ee.Image`. It masks an image.
- `projection()` must be called on an `ee.Image()`.
- Even if you filter your collection down to a single image, with `filterDates()` or some other filter, you still have an `ee.ImageCollection`. Calling `first()` returns you that `ee.Image()`, which you then can clip or ask for its projection.

Here's your modified script, showing how to pick the first image in a collection and clip it:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([12.49231, 41.89024]).buffer(10000)

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2001-12-31')
  .select('LC_Type5')
  .first()
  .clip(geometry);

print('MODIS projection:', modis.projection());
Map.addLayer(modis.randomVisualizer())
Map.centerObject(geometry)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/467cbccceda9919c21e73d769af51e20

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for taking time out to answer my question. What if I don't want to use the .first() in my script, though, since I am expecting just one image as my output (LC_Type_5 in 2001 and in a specific region? Or is it wrong to assume that my output is only one image in this case, and that I always have to use .first?

Comment: You could filter your collection to your area of interest, then do `.mosaic()` instead of `.first()`.

Comment: Neither `clip()` nor `filterBounds()` works on these one-tile global images. I have a similar problem too.